# Partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{1-X^6}$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

How can I compute the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{1-X^6}$?

Comment: Hint: Use differences of squares and cubes formulas: $(1-x^6)=(1-x^3)(1+x^3)=(1-x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x)(1-x+x^2)$.

Comment: Why the -3? What is wrong with Q?

Comment: @Moti This is a question that contains no apparent effort: The OP should include what they've tried, what they're having trouble with, and what background they know about.

Comment: So guide him by asking what was his effort - we have here an opportunity to encourage and share...

Comment: @Moti The mouseover of the downvote arrow says "does not show any research effort," which is the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1-x^6}=\frac{A}{1-x}+\frac{B}{1+x}+\frac{cx+d}{1+x+x^2}+\frac{ex+f}{1-x+x^2}$$
 So you have to do summation and take the coefficients of powers of $x$ equal in both side  .Then you will be get a system of six equation of six unknowns which it will give you $a,b,c,d,e,f$.

Comment: GREAT ANSWER - leaves some work and learning curve to the asking...

Comment: i found $A=-1/6$, $B=1/6$, I compute $lim\frac{X}{1-X{^6}}=0$ then i found $c+e=-1/3$, i am stuck, help please

Comment: I also found $d+f=0$

Answer (score 0):

My tame computer algebra system tells me:

$$\frac{1}{1 - x^6}
    = \frac{2 + x}{6 (1 + x + x^2)}
        + \frac{2 - x}{6 (1 - x + x^2)}
        + \frac{1}{6 (1 + x)}
        + \frac{1}{6 (1 - x)}$$